# Getting absolute pathname of a file in c

Tags: c, linux, path

I'll describe the problem- I have a configuration file which has in its first line a path to a DIR- 
`char students_Dest[LINE_LENGTH];
FILE *f_Conf = fdopen(fd_Conf, "r");
fgets(students_Dest, DIR_LENGTH, f_Conf); //Getting the dest of the students DIR`

So I wrote the line to the buffer

Now, I opened the DIR with
`DIR *students_Dir = opendir(students_Dest);`

And in this directory there are more directories that each one of them has a `main.out` executable.

So i Wrote this code

```
struct dirent *dir_Entry;
char real_Student_Path[128];
while((dir_Entry = readdir(students_Dir)) != NULL){
                if((strcmp(dir_Entry -> d_name , ".") == 0) || (strcmp(dir_Entry -> d_name, "..") == 0))
                        continue;
                printf("%s\n", dir_Entry->d_name);
                realpath(dir_Entry->d_name, real_Student_Path);
                printf("%s\n", real_Student_Path);
```

But when I print `real_Student_Path` I get the relative path + cwd of this prog, not `students_Dest + dir_Entry` String. I think that I didnt understand realpath, But I cant understand what exactly.

Could anyone help me? Thank You!

Comment: Check the return value of `realpath`.

Comment: so basically it expands the relative path? Like instead of `./path` it prints `fullpath/path`? like of the cwd?

Comment: I solved it by using strcat, of the relative path and the path in the configuration file